# Azure DevOps API - test execution information - last outcome, and run date for group of test-cases

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I wanted to retrieve last outcome (pass/fail/other) and last run date for test-cases part of particular Product Backlog Item -- using Azure DevOps API.

On Test Plan UI page i can see outcome (but not last run date) --  i need to get something similar thru API call.   (Note that a test plan may have many test-suits/ hierarchy of folders, want to get all test-cases/results)

One way to get to the information seems ... for each test-case --> make API calls to get   test-suit/ test-plan/ test-runs/ test-results and find the outcome/completedDate
(issue here is for one test-case... you end up querying many test-plans/ unrelated test-runs/ unrelated test-results.    When I query test-runs or test-results I don't see way to make call with specific test-case, if someone knows about it that can also help.  )

Looking for ideas/ suggestion for efficient ways to do this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> On Test Plan UI page i can see outcome (but not last run date) -- i
> need to get something similar thru API call.

Double click a test case, you will get all Outcome and TimeStamp information about this case.

[image]

> When I query test-runs or test-results I don't see way to make call
> with specific test-case

Do you need a list of run history of a particular test case? If so , you can try this [rest api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/test%20history/query?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0):

```
POST https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/test/Results/testhistory?api-version=5.0-preview.1
```

Or you can retrieve what you need from the [test results](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/results/list?view=azure-devops-server-rest-5.0) according to the test case name.

```
https://{instance}/{collection}/{project}/_apis/test/Runs/{runId}/results?api-version=5.0
```

Update:

You can first use [Get Points By Query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/points/get%20points%20by%20query?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0#by-test-case-id) rest api , then according to the lastResult id in the response, use [Results-Get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/results/get?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0#examples) rest api to get detailed information

Comment: Thanks for response @Hugh. From UI view -- what you are showing is good... but what I want to see is in single view test-case-id, last-testRunResult-outcome, last-testRunResult-date (without having to hop to test result / history for each case) -- is there any way?. **More important for me is API call to get t  last-testRunResult-outcome, last-testRunResult-date  for test-case-id data**  (even if I have to make couple of calls to get to it that's fine).

Comment: For your suggestion on >>  Do you need a list of run history of a particular test case?  “…{organization}/{project}/_apis/test/Results/testhistory?api-version=5.0-preview.1",   if that can give me the information, yes  that can work…  will it always get me last run/test-result information (even if last run was 2 months old? Or there are restrictions)

**if you can post or point me to an example that will be great. b.t.w. is there any way to restrict what I can get back , or  make use of GraphQL?**

Comment: fyi -  I have manual test cases, as well as automated test cases

Comment: You can first use [Get Points By Query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/points/get%20points%20by%20query?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0#by-test-case-id) rest api , then according to the lastResult id in the response, use [Results-Get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/results/get?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0#examples) rest api to get detailed information

Comment: Thanks @Hugh, will check it out!

Comment: I have Dev17.M153.3,  for the "_apis/test/points?api-version=5.1-preview.2" request I get "Page not found. - Azure DevOps Server".   Strangely for "_apis/wit/workItems/1234?api-version=5.1"  it worked against same server and credentials, but not for the test/points.  Any suggestion? @Hugh

Comment: Sorry for the late reply . If you use Azure Devops Server 2019,please try [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/points/get%20points%20by%20query?view=azure-devops-server-rest-5.0#by-test-case-id) : `_apis/test/points?api-version=5.0-preview.2`

Comment: Thank you  @Hugh